# I'm not sure how to embed Javascript into a Wordpress Page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, embed

So I have a prayer times script that I want to embed into a wordpress page.
Here is the link to it: http://praytimes.org/manual/

There is basically a PrayTimes.js file that I have attempted to include into the header.php/page.php file without success.

the code that I would post in a regular HTML page would look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Daily Prayer Timetable </title>
    <style>
        body, td, th {font-family: verdana; font-size: 12px; color: #404040;}
        #timetable {border-width: 1px; border-style: outset; border-collapse: collapse; border-color: gray; width: 9em;}
        #timetable td, #timetable th {border-width: 1px; border-spacing: 1px; padding: 2px 4px; border-style: inset; border-color: #CCCCCC;}
        #timetable th {color:black; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; background-color: #F8F7F4;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../PrayTimes.js"></script>

<br>
<p align="center">Waterloo, ON, Canada<p>
<div align="center" id="table"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var date = new Date(); // today
    var times = prayTimes.getTimes(date, [43, -80], -5);
    var list = ['Fajr', 'Sunrise', 'Dhuhr', 'Asr', 'Maghrib', 'Isha', 'Midnight'];

    var html = '<table id="timetable">';
    html += '<tr><th colspan="2">'+ date.toLocaleDateString()+ '</th></tr>';
    for(var i in list)  {
        html += '<tr><td>'+ list[i]+ '</td>';
        html += '<td>'+ times[list[i].toLowerCase()]+ '</td></tr>';
    }
    html += '</table>';
    document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = html;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm just not sure how to embed this into a Wordpress page. I only need to use it once.

Answer (score 0):

You should put scripts between `head` tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Daily Prayer Timetable </title>
    <style>
        body, td, th {font-family: verdana; font-size: 12px; color: #404040;}
        #timetable {border-width: 1px; border-style: outset; border-collapse: collapse; border-color: gray; width: 9em;}
        #timetable td, #timetable th {border-width: 1px; border-spacing: 1px; padding: 2px 4px; border-style: inset; border-color: #CCCCCC;}
        #timetable th {color:black; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; background-color: #F8F7F4;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../PrayTimes.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<br>
<p align="center">Waterloo, ON, Canada<p>
<div align="center" id="table"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var date = new Date(); // today
    var times = prayTimes.getTimes(date, [43, -80], -5);
    var list = ['Fajr', 'Sunrise', 'Dhuhr', 'Asr', 'Maghrib', 'Isha', 'Midnight'];

    var html = '<table id="timetable">';
    html += '<tr><th colspan="2">'+ date.toLocaleDateString()+ '</th></tr>';
    for(var i in list)  {
        html += '<tr><td>'+ list[i]+ '</td>';
        html += '<td>'+ times[list[i].toLowerCase()]+ '</td></tr>';
    }
    html += '</table>';
    document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = html;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll keep that in mind. But this is not my code specifically =)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your theme header template.

But a proper way for doing this is to put your inline script in a separate js file and use [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) to add the two js files in your pages.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I've looked up `wp_enqueue_script` and I've attempted to add it to the header, the functions.php, with no luck.

I'm just really confused on what to do.